# Structure of state object in redux

Tags: javascript, redux

What is the best practice for structuring the state object in **Redux** in relation to related objects.

Example:

`User` has-one `Organisation`

**With the above schema, where we also have a list of organisations is the following example a good idea?**

```js
{
    user: {
        id: 1,
        organisation_id: 3,
        first_name: 'Andrew',
        last_name: 'McLagan',
        email: 'andrew@example.com',
        organisation: {
            name: 'Foo Bar Co.'
            suburb: 'Booklyn',
            phone: '123-123-000',
        },
    },
    orgnaisations: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Facebook'
            suburb: 'Booklyn',
            phone: '000-000-000',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Twitter'
            suburb: 'Manhattan',
            phone: '456-456-000',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Foo Bar Co.'
            suburb: 'Booklyn',
            phone: '123-123-000',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Some Org.'
            suburb: 'Bronx',
            phone: '642-642-000',
        },                      
    ]
}
```

Or would it be better to access the users organisation by:

```js
const organisation = state.organisations[user.organisation_id];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to access the user organizations through their ID. Here is a possible way to organize your state:

```js
{
  user: {
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'Andrew',
    last_name: 'McLagan',
    email: 'andrew@example.com',
    organization: 3,
  },
  organizations: {
    1: {id: 1, name: 'Facebook', suburb: 'Booklyn', phone: '000-000-000',},
    2: {id: 2, name: 'Twitter', suburb: 'Manhattan', phone: '456-456-000'},
    3: {id: 3, name: 'Foo Bar Co.', suburb: 'Booklyn', phone: '123-123-000'},
    4: {id: 4, name: 'Some Org.', suburb: 'Bronx', phone: '642-642-000'},
  }
}
```

#### Using vanilla Redux

If you want to get the current user and his organization, you can use the following selector:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.user,
    organization: state.organizations[state.user.organization]
  }
}
```

The direct access using its ID will be a performance win. You can still easily query all stored organizations:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    organizations: Object.values(state.organizations),
  }
}
```

#### Using reselect

If you care about performance, using `reselect` would be a huge win. The first step is to define your selectors:

```js
// Get a list of all organizations
const getAllOrganizations = createSelector(
  state => state.organizations,
  orgs => Object.values(orgs)
)

// Get the current user
const getUser = state => state.user

// Get the current user's organization
const getUserOrganization = createSelector(
  [
    state => state.user,
    state => state.organizations,
  ],
  (user, orgs) => orgs[user.organization],
)
```

You could now use those selectors to update your `mapStateToProps` functions. The two described above would be:

```
// Get the current user and his organization
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: getUser(state),
    organization: getUserOrganization(state),
  }
}

// Get all organizations
const mapStateToProps = getAllOrganizations
```

Comment: :-) awesome. One Question... What about if there is only ever a single organisation. THEN is it ok to nest it in `user`

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan I guess yes. But the more you normalize your store, the easier it will be to manipulate it.

Comment: okay, this makes me excited. One last question. For myself and other SO users can you point us to the location of an article or documentation on this pattern?

Comment: The section [Computing Derived Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) in Redux's doc explains this pattern.